# Tail field of a sequence of events and relation between sigma algebra and dependence

Tags: probability-theory

before starting I should mention that I have already read (at least) most related questions and it still doesn't make any sense to me.
I've recently started studying probability theory and I'm reading "A first look at rigorous probability theory" by Jeffrey Rosenthal.
following definition is stated:

> Given a sequence of events $A_1, A_2,\cdots$ we define their *tail field* by
> $$\tau = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\sigma(A_i,A_{i+1},\cdots)$$

Also he mentions

> In words, an event $A \in \tau$ must have the property that for any $n$, it depends only on the events $A_n,A_{n+1},\cdots$; in particular, it does not care about any finite number of the events $A_n$.

The main problem for me is how generated $\sigma$_algebra relates to being independent?
Also when I was searching to understand what's going on, I encountered that usually $\sigma$_algebra is being treated as kind of measuring "information". I don't understand what information means here at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Does not depend" does not refer to stochastic independence here, it means you need no information about any finite number of events from the sequence to check whether some event in the tail $\sigma$ field occurred.

To give an example, the set of points that lie in infinitely many of the $A_n$'s is $$\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty A_n.$$ Intuitively, we don't learn anything about whether a point lies in this set or not by checking only finitely many sets in the sequence. Note that for any $i$, we have
$$\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty A_n=\bigcap_{m=i}^\infty\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty A_n,$$
and the set on the right lies clearly in $\sigma(A_i,A_{i+1},\ldots)$. Therefore, so does the set on the left. Since this works with all $i$, the set is in the tail field. This is also the kind of information you can get from the tail field.

There is a more explicit point about the tail field not depending on any of the $A_n$'s if they are all actually stochastically independent. In that case, Kolmogorov's zero-one law says that every set in the tail field has either probability $1$ or $0$. A measurable set that has probability $1$ or $0$ is actually independent of every measurable set (including itself).

In general, there is no real-valued random variable $X$ such that the tail field coincides with $\sigma(X)$. Proving this is had, though; see pages 12 and 13 [here](http://eudml.org/doc/268562) for the argument. This makes it hard to interpret the tail field as containing the information of some kind of experiment.